# SystemVerilog: difference between @(posedge clk) and ##1

Tags: system-verilog

In a SystemVerilog testbench, what's the difference between using @(posedge clk) and ##1 to wait until the next rising clock edge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are fewer places you can use ##1 because you need to setup a default clocking block context. This prevents you from using ##1 as a delay in any code declared in a package, like it would be in a class-based testbench using UVM. `##N` is functionally equivalent to `repeat(N) @(clocking_block_name)` except when N is 0. ##0 blocks until there is a clocking block event and does not block if there has already been a clocking block event in the current time slot.